# Terminology for tree subgraphs where non-neighbouring vertices are not connected by single ambient edges

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose $G=(V,E)$ is a connected graph and $T=(V_T, E_T)$ is a subgraph of $G$ that is a tree.

If we further suppose that any pair of vertices $v,w \in V_T$ that are not joined by a single edge in $E_T$ are also not joined by an edge in $E$, is there a standard name for this condition?  Informally, what I mean is that there are no single-edge shortcuts in the ambient graph that connect vertices in the tree that aren’t already joined by a single edge in the tree itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subgraph $T$ is an [induced subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph) of $G$.

Some authors use the term [induced tree](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/scott/Papers/inducedtrees.pdf) meaning an induced subgraph which is a tree.

Comment: I don't think this is the same condition as in the original post. Greg doesn't seem to be demanding that, for $v,w \in T$, the edge-sets $\text{Edge}_T(v,w) = \text{Edge}_G(v,w)$, which is your condition. Rather the condition is that $\text{Edge}_T(v,w) = 0 \implies \text{Edge}_G(v,w) = 0$. This is weaker.

Comment: As $T$ is a subgraph of $G$, it follows that $Edge_T(v,w)=1⟹Edge_G(v,w)=1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot that the standard convention/definition is that edges are determined by their endpoints. Thanks for correcting me!